# How to Convert 2019-01-01T00:00:00 to 2019-01-01 00:00:00 in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

Currently trying to convert a dataframe that has a date and time currently displayed in a column as 2019-01-01T00:00:00. However, I'm trying to convert the date and time to this format (2019-01-01 00:00:00) Have tried a few things using lubridate in R, but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `as.POSIXct`

```
as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T")
```

If we need to apply to a column

```
df$datecol <- as.POSIXct(df$datecol, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%T")
```

Or with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(str1)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2019-01-01T00:00:00"
```